# Issues with ui.router in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have discovered ui.router for building Single Page Application, but following a guide:

`angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module routerApp due to:(…)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:68(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4640forEach @ angular.js:321loadModules @ angular.js:4601createInjector @ angular.js:4523doBootstrap @ angular.js:1758bootstrap @ angular.js:1779angularInit @ angular.js:1664(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31763trigger @ angular.js:3207defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3497eventHandler @ angular.js:3485`

This is the index.html page:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="routerApp">
    <a ui-sref="table">Table</a>

    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is the app.js:

```
var routerApp = angular.module("routerApp", ['ui.router']);
routerApp.config('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('table', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'views/table.html'
    });
});
```

Thank you anticipately for the help, i really can't see the error..

Comment: What guide did you follow?

Comment: I see an error in inline annotation, square brackets are missing:  `routerApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('table', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'views/table.html'
    });
}]);
`

Comment: @alfredopacino where i should fix the code?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh, i saw where. thanks.

Comment: Try putting your script tags after your body.

Answer (score 0):

Injections should be an array.

Try add these like

```
var routerApp = angular.module("routerApp", ['ui.router']);
routerApp.config( [  '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
// -------------- ^  ---------------
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('table', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'views/table.html'
    });
}   ]   );
//  ^ and this -------
```